# Generic Object to Call Correct Method

Tags: c#

Overview: I'm writing a test program that I'm trying to break into 3 layers.  The top layer is the test that I'm running, it contains the state machine to be run (the order is the same for all devices).  The second layer is the device layer, it has all the commands specific to that device.  All devices have the same commands, but the syntax can be different.

Problem: How can I generically set the device type and call the correct command?  I have classDevice1 and classDevice2.  They both have a `.cmd1()` method.  In the top layer (test layer) I want to take a object and set it = to say classDevice1.  So in the test code I can just generically call `object.cmd1()` and it will call it from classDevice1.

[image]

Edit: I want my top layer to just be generic. It will called `object.cmd1()` for example. Object can be one of N classes I have, in which they all have a `cmd1()` method. How do I declare a generic object that points to a class?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you don't understand from your description or what you have problem implementing?

Comment: I want my top layer to just be generic.  It will called object.cmd1() for example.  Object can be one of N classes I have, in which they all have a cmd1() method.  How do I declare a generic object that points to a class?

Comment: Do you know about [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) ? A better example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: This does sound like a job for an interface

Comment: You could just use simple inheritance.  You could also use an interface.  But, read up on "Dependency Injection" (sometimes called "Inversion of Control").  That way, you can provide a mechanism to "Inject" your devices (sometimes known as a "plug-in" model in this context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statergy Pattern. [Here](https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern) is a code example.

[image]